# My function doesn't work twice in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, event-handling, dom-events

I have a table with numerous rows and columns and want to change the placeholder text, 'Cell 1' and 'Cell 2' (in column 1 and 2), within the ***td*** cells to 'Success'.

I have written a function to do this, but it only changes the first cell when I click it and no others when I try to click them.

```
document.querySelector('td').addEventListener('click', button8Click);

function button8Click() {
    document.querySelector('td').innerHTML = "Success";
}
```

I need to specifically target the *td* element, and thought I did so but I am at a standstill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `querySelector()` method returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document. 
If you need to add function to all the `td` elements try

```
 Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('td')).forEach(it => {it.addEventListener('click', button8Click)})
```

Also you need to change you function to identify which row is clicked and should be changed.

```
function button8Click(event) {
    event.target.innerHTML = "Success";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I see where my mistake was!